# How does temperature correspond to number of particles produced?

Tags: black-holes, thermal-radiation

I'm looking to calculate the number of particles per unit time produced by a Schwarzschild black hole through Hawking radiation. I know that the temperature of the black hole goes as $\kappa/2\pi$, but how does this correspond to the number of particles produced per unit time?